# Date Variable is not Carry Over to Function for Query String

Tags: sql, powershell

I receive this error:

> ExecuteSqlQuery : Must declare the scalar variable "@date".

I call the query as such: `ExecuteSqlQuery -server "sqlbox" -database "dbname"` and I receive the `date` variable error.  You can see my query statement uses the variable `m.created_date >= @date`.
How do I correctly pass the `date` variable to query string so it runs in the function without an issue?  NOTE: the code works when I hardcode the `date` value.

```
Function ExecuteSqlQuery {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$server,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$database
    )
    Process
    {
        $date= $((get-date).AddSeconds(-120).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
        $getscriptinfo = "select m.created_date, a.engine_full_hierarchy as Location, e.exciter_name, e.engine_exciter_id as ExciterID, m.additional_data as ReasonDown from HugsAdminAmador.mv_audit m, HugsAdminAmador.exciter e, HugsAdminAmador.area_map a where m.object_id = e.exciter_id and e.area_map_id = a.area_map_id and m.created_date >= @date and m.additional_data like '%NewStatus=DOWN%' and m.additional_data not like '%autonomous%'"
        $scriptscon = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $scriptscon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=true"
        $scriptcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $scriptcmd.Connection = $scriptscon
        $scriptcmd.CommandText = $getscriptinfo
        $scriptcmd.CommandTimeout = 0

        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

        try
        {
            $scriptscon.Open()
            $Reader = $scriptcmd.ExecuteReader()
            # if reader returns data create an array of the error data for the potential alert.
            If ($Reader.HasRows) {
       
                $obj = $Reader | foreach {
                $row = $_;  
                #the left naming is for the column headers in the email.
                new-object psObject -Property @{ 
                CreateDate = $row.Item("created_date")
                ReasonDown = $row.Item("ReasonDown")
                ObjectID = $row.Item("object_id")
                }
 
             }
       
           }
           return $obj
        }

        catch [Exception]

        {
           # Write-Warning "Get-ExecuteScripts (Connection: [$server].[$database])"
           # Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
           # Write-Warning "Query: $getscriptinfo --Id $scriptid"
        
            Write-Error $_
            $ErrorEvent = @{
            LogName = 'Exciter_Log'
            Source = 'Exciter_Health'
            EventID = 333
            EntryType = 'Information'
            Message = $_
            }

            Write-EventLog @ErrorEvent

        }

        finally

        {
            $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
            $scriptscon.Dispose()
            $scriptcmd.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you planning to supply the cutoff date? Via a parameter? Or do you want to always the same value? Or perhaps a value relative to the current time?

Comment: this is a date/time value that works in a previous script perfectly - its to get the date/time at the time of query.  this works perfectly - $date= $((get-date).AddSeconds(-120).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))

Comment: PS I:\> $date= $((get-date).AddSeconds(-120).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"))

PS I:\> echo $date
03-30-2021 09:50:42